# A tutorial project for learning React - Chat app

Tags: performance, beginner, react.js, jsx

I am trying to learn React basics and completed a chat app. My main purpose was to create user-specific text areas and preserve the draft when changing between people. Beforehand I had some trouble with the ContactList and posted it on StackOverflow. Thankfully it got solved and I finished this assignment. I don't know if the code is any good, what can I do to improve it and are there any logical mistakes? I only used React documentation and Stack Overflow to get help. This is my first solo project so I am open to any improvements and suggestions.

```
//App.jsx
import { useState } from 'react'
import ContactList from './ContactList';
import './App.css'
import Chat from './Chat';

export default function App() {

  const [selectedContact, setSelectedContact] = useState(() => contacts[0]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState({
      0:"",
      1:"",
      2:"",
  })

  function handleTextChange(e){
      setMessages({
          ...messages,
          [selectedContact.id]: e.target.value
      })
  }

  function handleButtonClick(contact , event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedContact(contact);
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <ContactList handleButtonClick={handleButtonClick} contacts={contacts}  />
      <Chat contact={selectedContact} handleTextChange={handleTextChange} messages={messages}/>
    </div>
  )
}
  

const contacts = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Taylor', email: 'taylor@mail.com'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Alice', email: 'alice@mail.com'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Bob', email: 'bob@mail.com'},
  ];
```

```
// Chat.jsx
export default function Chat({ contact, handleTextChange, messages }) {
  return (
    <div className="input-area">
      <textarea
        className="text-area"
        placeholder={"Chat to " + contact.name}
        value={messages[contact.id]}
        onChange={handleTextChange}
      ></textarea>
      <button key={contact.id} className="personName">
        Send to {contact.email}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//ContactList.jsx
export default function ContactList({ handleButtonClick, contacts }) {
  return (
    <div className="contact-buttons">
      {contacts.map((contact) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={contact.id}
            className="personName"
            onClick={(event) => handleButtonClick(contact , event)}
          >
            {contact.name}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not bad for an assignment. Just going top to bottom:

## App.tsx

You reference `contacts` before defining it. This works in JS because the declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), and the function referencing it doesn't get called until after `contacts` is initialized. Though it works, it's bad practice and can complicate debugging. I would move `contacts` to above `App`.

---

Not sure why you use an [initializer function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters) to initialize the `selectedContact` state. You can just initialize it directly like this: `useState(contacts[0])`

---

When initializing `messages`, you copy-paste the same IDs as in `contacts`. You should build it using the actual `contacts` instead, maybe something like this:

```js
useState(
  contacts
    .map(contact => contact.id)
    .reduce(
      (acc, id) => {
        acc[id] = '';
        return acc;
      },
      /* initialValue= */ {}
    )
);
```

But it's bad practice to use numbers as object keys. Almost always an object key will be a string. For `messages`, you're better off keeping an array of objects like `[{id: 0, message: ''}]`, or even using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

---

In `handleTextChange`, you set the state using the previous state directly. In more complex applications, this can create race conditions where your state changes can overwrite each other. To avoid this, set this state using an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-parameters), like this:

```js
setMessages(prevMessages => ({
  ...prevMessages,
  [selectedContact.id]: e.target.value,
}));
```

## Chat.jsx

Your component doesn't need to know about the entire `messages` object. It clutters the information present and in more complex applications may cause unnecessary rerenders. Prefer accepting a single `message` and calling your component with `messages[contact.id]`.

## ContactList.jsx

When iterating `contacts`, for arrow functions that directly return a value, you can skip the braces and `return`. Like this:

```
{contacts.map((contact) => (
  <button ... >
    ...
  </button>
))}
```

---

This is the opposite case. When defining `onClick`, you expect `handleButtonClick` to return nothing. But this kind of usage can be dangerous if it unexpectedly returns a value. You should wrap the call in braces to make this explicit, like this:

```
onClick={(event) => {
  handleButtonClick(contact, event);
}}
```

## Overall

Your code has stylistic inconsistencies and is missing some typical stylistic conventions for JS. For example:

- Trailing commas in some objects, not in others
- Semicolons in some places, not in others
- 2-space indents in some places, 4-space in others
- Whitespace separating some function declarations, not others
- Other inconsistent whitespace elsewhere

A good linter/formatter can fix most of these automatically. If you use VS Code, it should come by default.

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable comments about my project. I will try to avoid these mistakes in my new projects. Thank you for giving me the opportunity to become a better developer. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Crehara No problem. I made these same mistakes too when I first started out, as did everyone else. Practice and feedback will make your projects better.